# Crawling redirected urls with scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

Im trying to use scrapy to crawl `www.mywebsite.com`.

`www.mywebsite.com` is hosted on a free host with the url `www.mywebsite.freehost.com`. I am redirecting the free host to my paid domain.

The problem here is that scrapy ignores the redirect and the end result is that 0 pages are scraped.

How do I tell scrapy that I need it to crawl the redirected url? I only need it to crawl the redirected url and not other urls that lead out of the website (like facebook pages etc.)

```
2016-11-27 14:48:42 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2016-11-27 14:48:42 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2016-11-27 14:48:42 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2016-11-27 14:48:44 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.mywebsite.com/> (referer: None)
2016-11-27 14:48:44 [scrapy] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.mywebsite.freehost.net': <GET www.mywebsite.freehost.net>
2016-11-27 14:48:44 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2016-11-27 14:48:44 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
```

Answer (score 1):

The logs show that your request is being filtered:

```
DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.mywebsite.freehost.net': <GET www.mywebsite.freehost.net>
```

Add that domain `freehost.net` to your `allowed_domains` list, or remove `allowed_domains` from your spider to allow every domain.